# Record-triggered Flow Scheduled Path only works in debug?

Tags: visual-workflow, automation, scheduled-flow

so my requirement is this: A case should be automatically updated (status set to open) 5 days after the last modified date from the case (with some conditions). As an extra there should be an auto-task created which stated exactly this.

When I debug the flow with a case it looks good. When I activate the flow nothing shows up in the monitor. Even setting the time to 5 minutes (instead of 5 days) did nothing.

Here is what I have so far:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

So what did I do wrong?
Please help.

Kind regards
Alex

Comment: Given the way you set up the Flow, if you are using an existing Case, you need to update it such that the fields in the entry conditions change such that the formula becomes true when it was false before you updated the Case.

Comment: Hmm, ok, thanks. So there is no other way or flow to prevent that? Because then I can/ have to do every case manually.

Comment: sounds like you have legacy Cases ... if so, then you need to use Data Loader or an anonymous apex script to coerce the Cases into a true condition.  Sometimes, when I'm faced with this situation, I add a hidden field on the object and on the flow entry conditions called `Coerce_to_Flow_X_entry_conditions__c` (boolean) and use data loader  to set to true on legacy cases

Comment: Thanks cropredy. So this kind of flow would only work for future cases. At least that´s what I see in the monitor logs. To achieve it for "untouched" cases I need a real scheduled flow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have legacy Cases that you want the flow to apply to.

Flows will only execute if a Save event occurs on the record. Legacy cases will not undergo save operations in most situations

To coerce legacy cases into the flow you have some options

- Toggle those cases such that the flow entry conditions would be false and then toggle back so the entry condition is true.  You could do this with Data Loader or anonymous Apex.  It looks like you don;t have to go too far back in time
- Add a new custom field on Case called `Is_Coerced_Into_MyFlow__c` (checkbox, default false)

  - Add that field as an OR condition to the Flow entry criteria
  - Use Data Loader or anonymous Apex to set the checkbox to true for the relevant records
  - Be sure to clear the field after all the coercions (either in the flow itself or via other means)
- You could use a Schedule-triggered flow but this can only run once per day and would have to look back several days each time it ran. I'd avoid this route given that record-triggered flows with scheduled paths is the preferred solution for this use case

Comment: Hi cropredy, thanks for your feedback. But again - without touching the cases and modify the last modify date nothing will happen. At least that´s what is showing it to me in the flow monitor. But ok, will tell my users.

Comment: there's no way to avoid updating the case (and hence changing the last modified date) if you want existing cases to enter the flow. Record-triggered flows only work on DML events.  I suppose you could write a schedule-triggered flow that duplicates your logic to handle the legacy cases

Comment: Ok, thanks copredy. At least good to know (and already learned something new).

Comment: sounds like this answered your question; at your convenience and a service to the Community, use the checkmark to note as "accepted".

Comment: Sure, sorry. Done. Fairly new to stackexchange.